# Trying to prove that $x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})\ge\pi \cos(\frac{\pi}{x})$ for $x\ge 1$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry, inequalities, proof

As an intermediate step, consider the function:

```
f[x_] := x Sin[Pi/x]
```

I want to prove that this function is increasing for $x\ge 1$. This can be done with the first derivative. We have to prove that $f'[x]\ge 0$ for $x\ge 1$. First I tried:

```
FullSimplify[f'[x] >= 0, x >= 1]
(*Out: x Sin[π/x] >= π Cos[π/x] *)
```

Then I realized that Mathematica probably doesn't know about the inequality $\tan(x)>x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$. So I tried:

```
FullSimplify[f'[x] >= 0, x >= 1 && ForAll[y, 0 < y < Pi/2, Tan[y] > y]]
(*Out: x Sin[π/x] >= π Cos[π/x] *)
```

This inequality seems to be easy, I tried replacing `x >= 1` with `x >= Pi` and I get the same result. How can I properly use Mathematica to prove some theorems like this one?

EDIT: The main point of the problem is not trying to prove that the function is increasing (that is the motivation of the problem) , the main point is trying to prove that 
$x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})\ge\pi \cos(\frac{\pi}{x})$ for $x\ge 1$ using that $\tan(x)>x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$, i.e. i want to use the proving features of Mathematica.

Comment: If you don't time for a full proof, then plotting is a very practical solution. It removes all doubt, and can even help you see how to obtain the proof.

Comment: Build-in function to *Prove* in MMA `11.3`: `{AsymptoticGreaterEqual[x*Sin[Pi/x] , Pi Cos[Pi/x], x -> 2], 
 AsymptoticGreaterEqual[x*Sin[Pi/x] , Pi Cos[Pi/x], x -> Infinity]}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The proof of the original statement that $f(x)\equiv x\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ is a monotonically increasing function of $x$ for $x>1$ can be done as follows:

First, we show that the *second derivative* $f''(x)$ of the function is negative:

```
Simplify[D[x Sin[π/x], x, x] < 0, Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

> True

This means that the *first derivative* $f'(x)$ is a **monotonically decreasing** function of $x$ for $x>1$.

Now we show that the derivative of the function approaches zero as $x\to\infty$:

```
Limit[D[x Sin[π/x], x], x -> ∞]
```

> 0

Since the derivative has been shown to be decreasing and to have a limit of zero for $x\to\infty$, it follows that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x>1$. This proves the desired statement about $f(x)$.

**Edit**

To take the other route proposed in the edited version of the question, you could do the following:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x}, x > 1 && Tan[π/x] >= π/x, f'[x] >= 0], Reals]
```

> True

**Edit 2**

In the `Resolve` statement above, `ForAll` has three arguments: the variable `{x}`, a *condition*, and the statement to be proved. In words, this says the following: for all $x$ that satisfy the condition $x>1$ *and* $\tan(\pi/x)\ge \pi/x$, it holds that $f'(x)\ge0$. Of course, the condition can actually be simplified because the tangent inequality as stated here only holds for $x>2$.

To make the condition fully consistent with the desired interval $x>1$, we simply have to replace $x$ by $2 x$ in the tangent inequality. This leaves the inequality unaffected but extends its range of validity to $x>1$. Therefore, we get the following statement that can be fed to Mathematica:

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, x > 1 && Tan[π/(2 x)] >= π/x/2, f'[x] >= 0], Reals]
```

> True

Comment: Simple, to the point. I've omitted the second-derivative part in my answer, because the inquirer wasn't (IMHO) totally clear about what he was asking. +1

Comment: This is indeed a neat solution to my problem, but my question wasn't too clear, i edited it.

Comment: @Diego S. I think I understand what you're after. I've added a suggestion for how to use your additional assumption about tan(x) in the proof.

Comment: @Jens, +1 well done.

Comment: @Jens You are the only one that understood me. Your approach is good but not fully correct since `Tan[Pi/x]>=Pi/x` is not true for all `x > 1`. I tried `Resolve[ForAll[x, x > 1 && (0 < x < \[Pi]/2 \[Implies] Tan[x] > x), 
  f'[x] >= 0] ]` but didn't work. Maybe i'm asking too much from Mathematica. Can you make this work please?

Comment: @Diego, that's easily fixed. I've added an edit to that effect.

Comment: (+1) Both clear and straightforward.  Extra kudos for successful mind reading (being the only one able to understand the question :-)).

Comment: @Jens thank you very much, Mathematica seems a tricky tool for proving theorems.

Answer (score 15):

***Mathematica*** often responds well when provided a little expert assistance.  Let's focus on techniques that have a wide application rather than just to this problem.

1. **Can the function be decomposed into simpler pieces?**  Yes, obviously: $f(x)$ is the product of $x$ and $\sin{\pi / x}$.  Both are obviously increasing for $x \in [1,2]$.  After that, $\sin{\pi / x}$ turns around: it decreases while $x$ continues to increase.  The challenge is to show that the increase in $x$ overpowers the decrease in the rest of the function.  However, perhaps we have accomplished something: we can focus on the cases $x \ge 2$.
2. It can be more difficult, both theoretically and computationally, to determine characteristics of a function on an infinite (or noncompact) set like the interval $[2,\infty)$ than it is to work on a compact (finite) set.  From the appearance of $\pi/x$ in $f$ and the infinite limit of its domain, it is both natural and immediate to attempt the **change of variable** $y = 1/x$.  Because this change reverses the direction of $x$, we now wish to show that $g(y) = \sin{\pi y}/y$ is *decreasing* on the interval $[0, 1/2]$.

Let's begin a *Mathematica* implementation by creating $g$ and its derivative:

```
ClearAll[g, dg];
g[y_] := Sin[\[Pi] y] / y;
dg[y_] := Evaluate @ D[g[y], y]
```

**Why not try the obvious:** can we demonstrate that the derivative of $g$ is everywhere negative on this interval simply by requesting its supremum?

```
Maximize[{dg[y], 0 < y <= 1/2}, y]
```

The only solution is `y -> 0` (reached in 0.11 seconds).  This technique exploits two properties of `Maximize` announced in its documentation:

> Maximize will return exact results if given exact input.
>
> If the maximum is achieved only infinitesimally outside the region
>   defined by the constraints, or only asymptotically, Maximize will
>   return the supremum and the closest specifiable point.

*Mathematica* issues a warning message, because this is a boundary value and in fact `dg` is not defined at $0$, so to be sure, let's check:

```
 In[3]:= Limit[dg[y], y -> 0]
Out[3] = 0
```

Whence--because the supremum is $0$ and occurs uniquely at $y=0$--the derivative of $g$ is non-positive throughout $[0,1/2]$ and negative on $(0,1/2]$, *QED.*

**This problem can also be solved** via Taylor's Theorem (*with remainder,* not just naive inspection of the coefficients) by computing the power series of $g$ around $0$ out to first order and analyzing the remainder term.  It becomes so trivial with this approach that *Mathematica*'s power is unneeded, so I won't pursue the details here.  It is noteworthy, though, that this solution is available only for *g*, not for *f* (where the expansion would be around $\infty$, which doesn't accomplish anything in this case).

---

**More generally,** when tackling more complex or recalcitrant problems, try to decompose them into simpler pieces; use mathematical identities to reformulate the subproblems; attack the subproblems in multiple ways (rather than focusing on just one method, such as that based on a tangent identity in this problem); and let mathematical principles guide you.

Answer (score 5):

I have no rigorous training in mathematics - I'm not quite sure what constitutes a *proof* and what doesn't.

*How can I properly use Mathematica to prove some theorems like this one?* Well, what you can do is use *Mathematica* to help visualise the function as well as computing derivatives, integrals or limits. My approach is a bit hacky :)

**The function**

Okay, so we're dealing with
`x Sin[Pi/x]`
which is, obviously, a periodic function. It is also even (its plot is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) and 
`x Sin[Pi/x] == -x Sin[Pi/-x]` evaluates to `True`). The fact that the function is even is interesting if you want to generalize your "proof".

From the plot of `Sin[x]`,

[image: Sin[x]]

you can get a good idea of what the plot of `x Sin[Pi/x]` will look like, even before asking *Mathematica* to generate it. The fact that `Sin[x]` has a value between 0 and 1 while $ 0\lt x \leq \pi$ is obvious from the graph. What is also obvious is that the function's value has *negative* sign from $\pi \leq x \leq 2\pi$.

**What are we expecting?**

We're expecting a sinusoidal with ascending amplitude and frequency (the `x` multiplying `Sin[Pi/x]`). We can guess that because at values of `x` below 1, we will be evaluating the sine of a number *larger* than $\pi$, this trend being reversed at `x=1`. What happens after `x=1`? Let's ask *Mathematica*.

**Plotting the functions**

It turns out we were right about the amplitude and frequency. Right up to a point, at `x=1` - past this point, there are no more zeros. There's no *need* to go further, because it is obvious that our function has an asymptote. But what if we had our `PlotRange` wrong, and the (presumably more complicated) function really *does* have zeros after `x=1`? Let's again ask *Mathematica*.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It turns out that the limit of our function

```
Limit[x Sin[Pi/x], x -> \[Infinity]]
```

is $\pi$. Confirmation of asymptotic behaviour.

**What about $\pi \cos (\frac{\pi}{x})$?**

You could take a guess like we did before, or simply not bother and ask *Mathematica* right away.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is clear from this image that the inequality $x \sin (\frac{\pi}{x})\geq \pi \cos (\frac{\pi}{x})$ *can* be valid for $x \geq 1$. To confirm, we need to check the limit of the cosine function with

```
Limit[Pi Cos[Pi/x], x -> \[Infinity]]
```

which also evaluates to $\pi$. Good news.

**But how can I prove it's *increasing*?**

As halirutan said, you can use derivatives. As a non-mathematician, I would be convinced by the plots of the functions, and their limits. If you want to know *how fast* each function converges to $\pi$, then go ahead and take a look at each function's first/second derivative plot.

This approach might not qualify as rigorous, but I think it shows how you can use *Mathematica* to walk through math problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's 5am here and no, I'm not *already* up; so be warned. It seems `Reduce` cannot really help here but maybe someone else finds a direct way to do it. In the meantime you could take your derivative `f'[x]`

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \sin \left( \frac{\pi }{x} \right) -\frac{\pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)}{x}$$

$x$ can have values from 1 to infinity and we need to show, that the above expression is always positive. Keeping in mind the interval for $x$ we could make a substitution to simplify the expression

```
f'[x] /. x :> Pi/y
```

which leads us to an easier problem to prove

$$\sin (y)-y \cos (y)>0$$

Now you could subtract $\sin(y)$ and then divide by $\cos(y)$. In the division step you have to take care, because remember $y$ runs from $\pi$ (when $x=1$) to 0 (when $x$ goes to infinity) and plotting this range for $\cos(y)$ shows

```
Plot[Cos[y], {y, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

that you have to make a case-by-case analysis. For $\pi/2 \leq y \leq \pi$ the cosine is negative and you have to turn the sign of the inequality. Therefore, you have to show

$$\tan(y)>y,\quad\quad 0 < y < \pi/2$$

and

$$\tan(y)<y,\quad\quad \pi/2 < y \leq \pi$$

You maybe have to think about what happens *at* $\pi/2$ and I'm sure there are easier ways to solve this, but the tangens inequality caught my eye since you already mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in M10, you can use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange). For example:

```
FunctionRange[{x Sin[π/x] - π Cos[π/x], x>1.}, x, y]
```

> 0 < y <= 3.33984

Hence it is true that:

```
x Sin[π/x] - π Cos[π/x] > 0
```

or equivalently:

```
x Sin[π/x] > π Cos[π/x]
```

for `x>1`. Similarly:

```
FunctionRange[{D[x Sin[π/x], x], x>1.}, x, y]
```

> 0 < y < 3.14159

implies that `x Sin[π/x]` is monotonically increasing for `x>1`.

Also, starting in M11, [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) has been enhanced to be able to resolve these kinds of propositions:

```
proposition = Exists[x, x>1, x Sin[π/x] <= π Cos[π/x]];
Reduce[proposition]
```

> False

So, there are no values of `x` greater than `1` where `x Sin[π/x] - π Cos[π/x] < 0`. Alternatively, the following must be true:

```
FullSimplify[!proposition] //TeXForm
```

> $\forall _{x,x>1}x \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)>\pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)$

Similarly:

```
Reduce[Exists[x, x>1, D[x Sin[π/x], x] <= 0]]
```

> False

shows that `x Sin[π/x]` is monotonically increasing for `x>1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trivial, but just for the sake of completeness: the inequality holds not only for `x>=1` but already for `x>=x0`, where

```
x0 = x /. FindRoot[x Sin[\[Pi]/x] == \[Pi] Cos[\[Pi]/x], {x, 0.7}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]

(* Out[122]= 0.6991556596428411966369319152386816172807303061005296218612315287681429432614\
994992474339172310490725 *)
```

Remark: x0/pi is correctly recognized by Wolfram Alpha as "1/CTa, where CTa is the smallest root of the Tanc function" (=Tan[z]/z)

Answer (score -1):

What about using Taylor series?

```
fp = Normal[Series[f'[1/y], {y, 1, 20}]] /. y -> 1/x

FullSimplify[fp >= 0, x >= 1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: You cannot proof something by a finite approximation. In this way I could proof you anything.

Comment: I know it is not rigorous but I think Taylor series are good as an aproximation of results. Ideally you should use the infinite terms in series.