# Using FindInstance to Prove No Solutions Exist

Tags: equation-solving, proof

For a small amount of background, I am currently working on an undergraduate research project in Combinatorial Geometry and I'm working on a case analysis for embedding spherical simplicial 2-complexes in $\mathbb{S}^2$ and looking at their properties as they relate to tuples of spheres in arbitrary sphere packings. If that made no sense, no problem.

I want to show that there does *not* exist a solution to the equation:

```
a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i == 16 π - 33 ArcCos[1/3] - ω
```

where

```
ω = π - 4 ArcCos[1/3] + 
2 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]]
```

With some bounds on $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$. I have tried inputting this into Mathematica as follows (with $\omega$ defined in a previous command)

```
FindInstance[
    a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i == 16 π - 33 ArcCos[1/3] - ω && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < a < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < b < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < c < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < d < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < e < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < f < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < g < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < h < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < i < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3], 
    {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Reals
]
```

It returns an input of `{}` which means that *Mathematica* couldn't find any solutions. This is a very good thing for me, but how can I formalize the fact that no such solutions exists other than "Mathematica couldn't find any solutions using the `FindInstance` command"?

Comment: This seems like a question for math.stackexchange.com.  *Mathematica* does not usually provide specific proofs (there is the Primality Proving Package).  Surely a blank `FindInstance` result is in no way a proof.  This question therefore becomes "how can I prove hypothesis X" which again, seems like a question for another site.

Comment: You could try to recast as linear (weak) inequalities over the rationals by slightly enlarging the bounds. If FindInstance/Reduce give no solutions to that, then there are no solutions.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can you explain further? Why? (thanks)

Comment: @Belisarius Linear programming over the rationals is fairly stable technology. It could have bugs, I guess. But that's not too likely. Reduce and FindInstance will use LP under the hood, if presented with a problem falling into that category. The one above does so, if i am seeing it correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. If  `FindInstance[ expr, vars, dom]` returns no instances - `{}`, it does not mean (in general) there are no solutions, i.e. **it does not prove anything** here.
2. Some kind of reasonable arguments you can get  making use of `Reduce`, if you change the head  of `FindInstance[ expr, vars, dom]` into `Reduce[ expr, vars, dom]` and evaluate it, that will return `False`. However this is not the unique way to proceed.
3. Since the problem is to demonstrate non-existance of solutions to the system of the equation and conditions, we can show that in a quite different way making a smart use of `N`.

First, let's use your `ω`  and plug it into your equation with the following notation (`L` and  `R` - respectively lhs and rhs of the equation, `Cond` the rest of conditions present in the problem),  so we have:

```
ω = Pi - 4 ArcCos[1/3] + 
    2 ArcCos[(2(1/2 + 1/8(-1-3Cos[4ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[3(1-1/16(1+3Cos[4ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]];

L = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;  

R =  Simplify[16 Pi - 33 ArcCos[1/3] - ω];

Cond = 
  ( ArcCos[1/3] < a < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && ArcCos[1/3] < b < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < c < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && ArcCos[1/3] < d < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < e < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && ArcCos[1/3] < f < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < g < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && ArcCos[1/3] < h < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
    ArcCos[1/3] < i < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3]);
```

now the rhs of the equations i.e `R` is much nicer :

```
R
```

> ```
> 15 Pi - 29 ArcCos[1/3] - 2 ArcCos[2 Sqrt[2/57]]
> ```

Let's  sum inequalities in the conditions to get bounds for `L`:

```
Less @@ Plus @@ List @@@ Cond // N
```

> ```
> 11.0786 < a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i < 45.47
> ```

as well as

```
Plus @@ Cond[[All, 2]] === L
```

> ```
> True
> ```

thus we have

```
11.0786 < N[L]
```

and since the equation says :

```
L == R
```

we get a contradiction because

```
N[R]
```

> ```
> 9.05248
> ```

Thus we have no solutions at all.

Comment: This is a bit of a delayed follow-up, but how is using Reduce any more conclusive than using FindInstance? Wouldn't the output of Reduce be "False" if and only if the output to FindInstance was {}?

Comment: @Shane The answer could be realized if you compare how `Solve` and `Reduce` are different. I recommend reading e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)  `FindInstance` returns results in terms of replacement rules.

Comment: @Artes : You wrote: "If  `FindInstance[ expr, vars, dom]` returns no instances - `{}`, it does not mean (in general) there are no solutions, i.e. **it does not prove anything** here." -- What is the basis for this opinion? In fact, it contradicts the official Mathematica documentation. Go to reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html, click there on "Details and Options", and you will see this: "FindInstance[expr,{x1,x2,…}] **gives results** in the same form as Solve: {{x1->val1,x2->val2,…}} **if an instance exists**, and **{} if it does not** [emphasis mine]."

Comment: I would say something analogous with respect to `Solve`. ` Reduce` is more powerful.  Nevertheless since then `Solve` became smarter.  The main disadvantage is the output in terms of rules. This issue has been discussed more thoroughly here [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Answer (score 14):

For proving statements like this you can enter predicate logic quantifiers directly into Mathematica and let it try to `Resolve` the formula to a truth value.

First we state the problem ingredients

```
ω = FullSimplify[
      π-4 ArcCos[1/3]+2 ArcCos[(2 (1/2+1/8 (-1-3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]]))) / 
      Sqrt[3 (1-1/16 (1+3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]]
    ]
vars  = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};
eq    = Total[vars] == 16 π - 33 ArcCos[1/3] - ω //FullSimplify
conds = And @@ Thread[ ArcCos[1/3] < vars < 2 π - ArcCos[1/3] ]
```

and let `Resolve` do the work of proving

```
Exists[Evaluate[vars], conds, eq]
```

$$\exists _{\{a,\cdots,i\},\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)<\{a,\cdots,i\}<2 \pi -\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}a+\cdots+i+\frac{\pi }{2}=2 \sin ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{57}}\right)+29 \csc ^{-1}(3)$$

```
Resolve[%]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Nice and +1, anyway this should be corrected `\\FullSimplify` in `eq` to `//FullSimplify` or `//Simplify`.

Comment: oh yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke: I ended up having already solved this particular problem I asked in the question, but this technique happened to end up being very useful for something else I am now working on, so thank you!

Comment: That's good to hear, you're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Just a small remark: if the variables are angles then you should probably make the bounds periodic, using something like `Mod[a, 2 Pi]` instead of `a` in the conditions. Then you obviously get solutions to this trivial problem. Here I just did it for one of the variables:

```
FindInstance[
 a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i == 
   16 Pi - 33 ArcCos[1/3] - \[Omega] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < Mod[a, 2 Pi] < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < b < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < c < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < d < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < e < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < f < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < g < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < h < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3] && 
  ArcCos[1/3] < i < 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3], {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, 
  i}, Reals]

(*
==> {{a -> (11 Pi)/2 - 17 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
     3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  b -> (15 Pi)/4 - 8 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    1/2 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
      3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  c -> (15 Pi)/8 - 7/2 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    1/4 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
      3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  d -> (15 Pi)/16 - 5/4 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    1/8 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
      3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  e -> (15 Pi)/32 - 1/8 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    1/16 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
      3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  f -> (15 Pi)/64 + 7/16 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    1/32 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
      3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  g -> (15 Pi)/64 + 7/16 ArcCos[1/3] - 
    1/32 ArcCos[(2 (1/2 + 1/8 (-1 - 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])))/Sqrt[
      3 (1 - 1/16 (1 + 3 Cos[4 ArcCos[1/3]])^2)]], 
  h -> -(1/2) + 2 Pi - ArcCos[1/3], i -> 1/2 + ArcCos[1/3]}}
*)
```

More to the point of proving statements: you should look at `Resolve` and its use with `ForAll` and `Exists`. [This link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3599/245) has an example of a proof that uses `Resolve`.

Comment: I'm not sure why I should add my bounds on the angles to be periodic... I only consider it relevant to consider to internal angle which is bounded below $2\pi$.